# Is there any alternate way for CheckBox onClick Event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, webusercontrol

I have written one JavaScript function which would rise the event when the User clicks the CheckBox.

But I have already written some other function which too has to rise when the user clicks the CheckBox. I included that function on onClick event like below:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Checked='<%#Bind("Select") %>' onClick="CheckedTotal();" />
```

But now I want to include another function called "EnableLink" into that onClick event of the CheckBox. How to include this function to the CheckBox? I have tried to combine both the function as a single one. But it has become a complex one for me. So Is there any alternate way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this..quickest one

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Checked='<%#Bind("Select") %>' onClick="CheckedTotal(); EnableLink(); MoreClick();" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This will Help you,

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Checked='<%#Bind("Select") %>' onClick="CheckedTotal();EnableLink();" />
```

Answer (score 2):

1) .. onClick="CheckedTotal();myFn();" ..

2) .. onClick="someFn();" ..

```
 <script>
    function someFn(){
       CheckedTotal();
       myFn();
    }
 </script>
```

3) in *onload* of the window/page

```
document.getElementById('myCheckboxID').addEventListener('click', myFn,false);
```

UPDATE: myFn() = EnableLink();